# How to sum two functions horizontally?

Tags: function, sum

I want to add two (exactly about 99) functions (to be more specific: supply functions) horizontally. All functions are stepwise e.g.:

```
y(x>=x1 & x<x2) = a;
y(x>=x2 & x<x3) = b;
z(x>=x3 & x<x4) = c;
z(x>=x4 & x<x5) = d;
```

I have no idea how I can do it. Could anybody give me a clue? I would appreciate that.

Comment: What does it mean to add two functions horizontally? Could you give us a mathematical definition and/or the simplest non-trivial example you can think of?

Comment: Also, what programming language is this?

Comment: U w0t m8t? horizonal sum? the results of functions being assigned values? functions recieving the bitwise AND of booleans? I don't even. Not even Haskell.